# CSS transition transform z-index conflict in Safari (Works on Chrome / FF)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am playing around with CSS transition and rotate effects for displaying a business card. I got everything to function properly in Chrome and FF but in Safari it distorts the div.

I tried applying the following properties to no avail:

```
transform: translateZ(0px);
transform-style: flat;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/alchuang/pen/cksFy) for code and pics below:

Safari: 
[image: Safari]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Comment: I got the same problem with Safari. It's perfectly working in Chrome, FF, ... I know it has been a couple years - any solution?

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is an issue with stacking references and CSS transforms clashing.

Try adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the parent element of your card. That should form the transformed children to obey the z-index stacking.

If anyone else has some input on this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

try

This might be related to: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61824

Basically when you apply a 3D transform on the z-axis, the z-index can't be accounted for anymore (you're now in a 3 dimensional rendering plane, use different z-values). If you want to switch back to 2D rendering for child elements, use `transform-style: flat;`.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried adding `transform-style: flat;` as stated in my question but it doesn't rectify the behavior. It is working properly in Chrome and FF so I wonder if there's a work around in Safari to get it working.